# "No mouse support: mouse=a" error in vim

Tags: vim, vimrc

I am running a particular script and getting the following error :

```
  Error detected while processing /home/subhrcho/.vimrc:
  line   42:
   E538: No mouse support: mouse=a
```

This is the relevant portion of .vimrc file :

```
" In an xterm the mouse should work quite well, thus enable it.
 set mouse=a
```

Any idea as to what is wrong ?

P.S: I am using the following version of vim

> VIM - Vi IMproved 7.0 (2006 May 7, compiled Nov 12 2010 05:24:19)
>   Included patches: 1, 3-4, 7-9, 11, 13-17, 19-26, 29-31, 34-44, 47,
>   50-56, 58-64, 66-73, 75, 77-92, 94-107, 109, 202, 234-237

And my platform is :

> Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.8 (Tikanga)

Comment: Your Vim version is ancient (2006!!!). Go grab a recent package; you'll thank me later ;-)

Answer (score 11):

Alternatively, you could do this in your .vimrc:

```
if has('mouse')
  set mouse=a
endif
```

And the warning/error goes away...

Answer (score 2):

Looking up the error (`:help E538`) brings you to the help for the `'mouse'` setting:

> Only works for certain terminals
>   (xterm, MS-DOS, Win32, QNX pterm, BSD console with
>   sysmouse and Linux console with gpm).

Also, check whether your Vim (you didn't state neither platform nor version) is compiled with mouse support:

```
:echo has('mouse')
```

If it is, it's due to the terminal; use another. If it isn't, you first need to find or compile a Vim binary that has mouse support.

Comment: Will I have to execute the :echo has('mouse') command from inside vim?When i executed this from vim , I got 1 . What does it mean ?

Comment: Please see the question for version and platform

Comment: Which terminal do you use? `xterm`? `gnome-terminal`? It should work in those.

Comment: `has(mouse)` doesn't mean that the mouse works in your environment, it means that the feature is compiled in.

Comment: @IngoKarkat echo $TERM gives me xterm

Comment: Well, `$TERM` is not authoritative; it can be set by anything, and `xterm` is the generic value. What does the shortcut for your terminal actually launch? What does it's Help > About dialog say?

Comment: @Ingo I see . Help-->About  says "GNOME Terminal 2.16.0"

Comment: Hm, that should work. Could you try with a newer Vim version (7.3)?!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem and realized that only "vim-minimal" RPM was installed.

I installed vim-enhanced and suddenly "set mouse=a" works like a charm.